# create list-form according to mysql table

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

i' ve created a database using mysql and i'm using php (along with html of course) to retrieve/insert data to it.

i want to know how to create a form-list, which displayed options will change* according to a table in my database.

for example let's say i have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE COMPANY (
comp_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
comp_name varchar(30) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(comp_id) );
```

i want the list to have all the different company names for options, so the user can pick which company he wants.

*the company names are not standard, in the company table can happen changes, one day i may have comp1 and comp2 and the next comp3, comp4 and comp5.

so i cannot have a fixed code for that, i need the page to "read" the values from the table and create the form according to them.

hope you understand what i mean :P
thanks in advance!

Comment: So you want the company names in the options, then use any php loop to the display the list from the database.

Comment: @Mawia HLok, and how will i know how many are the companies to configure the loop? or how will i set a different value for every one of them?

Comment: Your question is not clear to me because you do not provide the codes you are working. I guess you want an html select box with dynamic options. To take the company name from the table, you can use for loop, foreach loop, while loop.

Answer (score 1):

Just fetch all the records from company table then populate select element from that data. To change company name, Just change it in table.

```
$mysqli  = new mysqli('127.0.0.1','root','','dbname');
if($mysqli->connect_errno){
echo $mysqli->connect_errno;
} else {
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM COMPANY';
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
    if(!$result){
        echo "Query Failed. ".$mysqli->error;
    } else {
        if($result->num_rows > 0){
        $html = "<select>";

        while($current_row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            $html .= '<option value="'.$current_row['comp_id'].'">'.$current_row['comp_name'].'</option>';

            }

            $html .= "</select>";   
            $result->free();//free the resultset memory
            echo $html;
        } else {
            echo "No Record Exists";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some semi-pseudo code based roughly on `mysqli` - connection assumed to be `$db`

This ought to give an idea how you can accomplish what you want.

```
$sql='select * from `company`';
$res=$db->query( $sql );

if( $res ){
    $html=array('<select name="company">');
    while( $rs=$rs->fetch_object() )$html[]="<option value='{$rs->comp_id}'>{$rs->comp_name}";
    $html[]='</select>';
    printf('%s',implode( PHP_EOL, $html ) );
}
```